# Sorviceworker in cross origin iframe

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I want to load a small plugin from domain B in an iframe on a page from domain A.
The plugin from domain B uses a service worker for optimal performance.

However, the SW can't be installed because there is no service worker object when the mage is loaded inside an iframe.
Is it not supported? (and what might be the reasoning if so?)

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        let registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(uri)
        registration.update()
    }else{
        console.log('sw iframe not installed')
        console.log(navigator)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By lots of trying and debugging I have found the answer:

- The origin site A is hosted via http
- The plugin from domain B is (obviously) via https

It seems serviceworker is blocked in an iframed https site if parent is http.

If anyone has the reasoning behind this, please let me know
(I don't see it)